# How to display flowcharts dynamically in java?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, graph, flowchart

I want to develop a java desktop application that takes some inputs from the user and store it in a database. After that, when user clicks on a button (say display) it displays the information, entered by him earlier, in a flowchart like format.

Can I display that information in the form of flowcharts?

Comment: Don't repost (now merged). Instead, consider clarifying this question (edit).

Answer (score 2):

You can try out [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html)

Comment: can I develop data flow diagrams dynamically based on the input entered by a user. How can integrate it with swings.

Comment: we have a couple of commercial products that use swing and JGraph. It works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html). It stores drawings in XML format that can be very easily emulated based on your data. We've used this approach in the past and it worked like a treat.

If you need the same functionality on the back-end, just take a look at their [yFiles library](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_about.html).

Answer (score 0):

You also could look at yWorks ( http://www.yworks.com/en/index.html ), another graphing library for java and .net (but a $$$ commercial product).

I like prefuse ( http://prefuse.org/ ) for graphs, even they stopped active development for the java lib a while ago, but you might need to do more coding with it to get a flowchart implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a drawing library for that. For example [JFDraw](http://www.jfimagine.com/).